# Create Xcode-like Outline View header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsoutlineview

OK, this what I'm trying to replicate :

[image]

I suppose that is an `NSOutlineView` - a "Source List"-type one actually.
I'm used to be working with `NSOutlineView`s with `ImageAndTextCell`.

- Is it a view-based `NSOutlineView` or should I still use `ImageAndTextCell`?
- How am I to draw a different background for this specific "Header" element?
- How would you go about it?

Comment: Well, it's the same on 10.6.x so I'd assume it's still cell based, not a view based table view - or, rather, a completely custom UI component. Apple has a nasty history of using those going waaaay back to even Classic Mac OS days :-/

Comment: @Jay Well, a custom UI component was what I was mostly thinking about - and perhaps wanted to avoid re-creating a component for yet another time. (Btw, I feel quite relieved that - at last - someone seems to get my question right. It seems most thought I was interested in replicating the tabs way-above (did I mention anywhere the word "tabs"??)) :-)

Comment: @NSAddict As I've already commented, your answer is fine; but not as an answer to **this** question.

Comment: @Dr.K - Yeah, well.. ;-) I'd suspect you could get something pretty close with the view based tableview nevertheless.. see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a view-based `NSTableView` and returning different views for the **header** and **item** rows (let's call them..)?

I suppose you could have a `NSTableViewDelegate` that would depending on what type is required return from its `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` method either a header-type or item-type view prototype depending on the row (index)?

Not sure if views returned by that method are allowed to have different heights or if you've got to handle that separately. If view-based table views are not smart enough to do it on their own you might have to implement `- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row` as well to set row heights appropriately for headers/items.

Comment: Interesting idea; I'll check it out! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Use a a NSTabView without the tabs for the content, for the buttons just use NSButtons but with no background only your image for the entire cell and set them up as radio button, make sure they are in a NSMatrix. You can then use NSOutlineView inside you tab view panels.

Comment: I'm not talking about the tabs. I was talking about the **Header** (containing "DRKit").